# node couchbase install error

Tags: couchbase, couchnode

I try to install `npm install couchbase`, it seems like installed correctly:

But when I run the following code:

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://127.0.0.1');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('default');

bucket.upsert('testdoc', {name:'Frank'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  bucket.get('testdoc', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result.value);
    // {name: Frank}
  });
});'
```

Give me the following error:

```
throw new Error('Failed to locate couchnode native binding'
```

**node_modules/couchbase/builderror.log:**

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\Labs\beersample-node\node_modules\couchbase
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Can you mention the version you're using?  Also, what VS do you have installed there?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you need not have a Visual Studio build environment and it looks, from the error, like yours is getting invoked here.  Can you try to do this from a shell where your VS environment isn't in the path?  That may let it follow the more common installation path.